# Record till the end of buffer using AudioRecord

Tags: android, udp

I have been trying to implement an android app that can transfer voice between two devices in real time. For this, on client side, I am implementing an AudioRecorder and planning to directly send the packets of byte arrays of fixed duration. In the server, I am planning to play that packets using AudioTrack. One thing I can't figure out is, Say I am using a buffer of size 1024 Bytes. After I start recording, How to stop the AudioRecord after it fills up that size?

I am trying this code

```
AudioRecord recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
44100, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO,
AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, bufferSize);
recorder.startRecording();
recorder.stop();
```

But this seems to stop recording as soon as the recording starts, but not after the buffer has completely filled.

Thanks.

Comment: How do you check what's in the buffer?

Comment: Maybe you can wait for recorder.getRecordingState() becomes RECORDSTATE_STOPPED when the buffer is full. (Untested).